# Laravel - Access relationship through other

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
entries  
- id 
- category_id 
- name  

field  
 - id  
 - category_id
 - name  

field_values  
- id  
- entry_id  
- field_id  
- value   

category  
 - id  
 - name
```

Each Category has certain fields. If I add an entry, I choose the category and I can enter the values for the field for the entry.

Let's say we have the Category "Venues". Venues has the custom field named "Capacity". If I add a news entry, I need to fill the field "Capacity".

This is how I read the fields and their values for an entry:

```
@foreach($data->field_values as $values)
    {{$values->field->name}}: {{$values->value}}
@endforeach
```

I can only access the field table through the "field_values" table. Isn't it possible to access field directly from entry maybe with an hasManyThrough ?

This (in Entry Model):

```
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Field', 'App\FieldValues');
}
```

throws the following mysql error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fields.field_values_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `fields`.*, `field_values`.`entry_id` from `fields` inner join `field_values` on `field_values`.`id` = `fields`.`field_values_id` where `field_values`.`entry_id` in (3))
```

Why I need to add a field_values_id to Field? Isn't there a different approach?

I just want to foreach through entry->field and not do it by entry_field_values->field

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the Fields for an entry, why not do a hasMany relationship ?

**Entry Model:**

```
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Field');
}
```

Then you can get all the fields for an entry as:

```
$fields = $entry->fields()->get();
```

Comment: because Entry and fields aren't related. There is no entry_id in field nor field_id in entry. Only the field_values are related to the entry.